# proposal flag and agreement flag in 802.1w RSTP BPDU packet

Tags: spanning-tree

For my current understanding of RSTP, the proposal flag and agreement flag should not be set to "1" at the same time, and they should also not be set when the network topology is stable, which means there is no topology change happens.

But when I check the RSTP BPDU packet of a Switch device, the following BPDU flags setting is shown.
[image: 802.1w RSTP BPDU packet]

Is there any mistake in my understanding?